# Laravel - How to make the application show the specific error to the user

Tags: laravel

I have Laravel-5.8 project code:

```
 public function store(StoreTypeRequest $request)
 {
    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id; 
    
    DB::beginTransaction(); 
    
    try{
        $data = Type::create([
            'name'                      => $request->name,
            'parent_id'                 => $request->parent_id,
            'max_score'                 => $request->max_score,
            'comment'                   => $request->comment,
        ]);
    
    $data1 = DB::table('types')->select('max_score')->where('id', $request->parent_id)->where('company_id', $userCompany)->whereNull('parent_id')->first();
    $data->update(['max_score1' => $data1->max_score]);
    
    DB::commit();  
    
    Session::flash('success', 'Type is created successfully');
    return redirect()->route('types.index');
    
    } catch (Exception $exception) 
    { 
          DB::rollback();
          Session::flash('error', 'Action failed! Please try again');
          return back();
      }        
}
```

When I submitted, I got this error:

> Action failed! Please try again

How do I make the application to show specific error, so that the user will be clear about what caused the error?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Catch an exception on using try-catch statements :

```
Use Exception;
```

```
try
{
   // write your codes here
}
catch(Exception $exception)
{
   dd($exception->getMessage());
}
```

If you want to catch `PDO Exception` :

```
use PDOException;
```

```
try
{
   //write your codes here
} 
catch(PDOException $e)
{
   dd($e->getMessage());
}
```

If above code isn't working then give a backslash \ before `Exception` & `PDOException`

Comment: You need the first one. I added both for them who will look the same